# How can i display month Name using onSelectedDayChange() for CalendarView in android

Tags: android, android-studio, calendarview

By default onSelectedDayChange() of calendarView diplay's month as an integer value like:- 1-1-2021.
But I want the format as 1-Jan-2021.
Please help out.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the ***DateFormatSymbols*** class and get the list of months in String

```
  calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            DateFormatSymbols dateFormatSymbols = new DateFormatSymbols();
            String mMonth = dateFormatSymbols.getMonths()[month - 1];
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Shay Kin.
It's working fine now.